# Insert Generator?

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

I'm just wondering if somebody can point me in the right direction for creating an insert generator within the confines of SQL? I have a Microsoft SQL database that I want to export to multiple anti-standard databases for some testing and think this would be a good method for moving the data.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you mean to tag with mysql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one built in to SSMS.   Tasks->Generate Scripts.... See this answer: [Script all data from SQL Server database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6799120/script-all-data-from-sql-server-database)

Also, check out [SSMS Tools Pack](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/).

Comment: Thank-you very much - I actually used SSMS to get the data from Access into Microsoft SQL in the first place, I didn't realize this was also available.

More for curiosities / educations sake - Is there a way to do something like this in SQL and if so what do you recommend I read up on to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to lead you to this post:

[What is the best way to auto-generate INSERT statements for a SQL Server table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982568/what-is-the-best-way-to-auto-generate-insert-statements-for-a-sql-server-table)

In which @ShaneFulmer posts:

http://vyaskn.tripod.com/code/generate%5Finserts.txt

Comment: Oh.. my bad, you are so right.. and I totally misread the post for wanting to export for just one table (and not the entire database), which might have taken longer than running the scripts in the link :( .. Should I remove my post?

Comment: Worth retaining for interests sake in my opinion - I think there's knowledge to be gained from it