# save the whole database to a query in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to save the whole database to a query in sql server 2008. I have experience with mysql and phpmyadmin, and over there I used to have a simple button to save the database, including constraints and basically everything, to a simple query.

that query basically recreates the database i created just as it was. I think you guys understand what I mean.

is there such an option in ms sql server? thank you in advance.

Comment: May be you want to take a look at [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6799120/script-all-data-from-sql-server-database)

Comment: thank you, bhupeshc, this is exactly what I was looking for. I just wasn't searching it properly, never thought about 'scripting' the database. cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate scripts to recreate the database structure in SSMS:

Right-click a database, choose `Tasks` > `Generate Scripts...` and go through the wizard.

You do not get insert scripts for all the data by default, you need to choose that in the `Advanced` options in the wizard, `Types of data to script` choose `Schema and data`/`Data only`/Schema only`

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server, I generally go with a backup/restore point of view.  You can backup your entire database to a file, and then choose to restore that database (To another name as I often use for recreating new test databases).

I don't know about creating a query out of the database, but the effect of both seems to be the same result.