# Duplicate Sql Server Table Definition Using Generated Create Statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to copy several tables definition from one database  to other database. I have found a way to generate create statement for every individual table that I need. However I cannot execute every 'create statement' that is generated. I expect that following script will recreate all table that match criteria in NEWDB database. However it didn't. It always recreate only one table instead of all tables that I need. I am not sql expert and I believe I am missing something here.

```
declare @sql varchar(8000)

select  @sql='create table [NEWDB].[' + OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(so.id) + '].[' + so.name + '] (' + o.list + ')' + CASE WHEN tc.Constraint_Name IS NULL THEN '' ELSE 'ALTER TABLE ' + so.Name + ' ADD CONSTRAINT ' + tc.Constraint_Name  + ' PRIMARY KEY ' + ' (' + LEFT(j.List, Len(j.List)-1) + ')' END
from    sysobjects so
cross apply
    (SELECT 
        '  ['+column_name+'] ' + 
        data_type + case data_type
            when 'sql_variant' then ''
            when 'text' then ''
            when 'ntext' then ''
            when 'xml' then ''
            when 'decimal' then '(' + cast(numeric_precision as varchar) + ', ' + cast(numeric_scale as varchar) + ')'
            else coalesce('('+case when character_maximum_length = -1 then 'MAX' else cast(character_maximum_length as varchar) end +')','') end + ' ' +
        case when exists ( 
        select id from syscolumns
        where object_name(id)=so.name
        and name=column_name
        and columnproperty(id,name,'IsIdentity') = 1 
        ) then
        'IDENTITY(' + 
        cast(ident_seed(so.name) as varchar) + ',' + 
        cast(ident_incr(so.name) as varchar) + ')'
        else ''
        end + ' ' +
         (case when IS_NULLABLE = 'No' then 'NOT ' else '' end ) + 'NULL ' + 
          case when information_schema.columns.COLUMN_DEFAULT IS NOT NULL THEN 'DEFAULT '+ information_schema.columns.COLUMN_DEFAULT ELSE '' END + ', ' 

     from information_schema.columns where table_name = so.name
     order by ordinal_position
    FOR XML PATH('')) o (list)
left join
    information_schema.table_constraints tc
on  tc.Table_name       = so.Name
AND tc.Constraint_Type  = 'PRIMARY KEY'
cross apply
    (select '[' + Column_Name + '], '
     FROM   information_schema.key_column_usage kcu
     WHERE  kcu.Constraint_Name = tc.Constraint_Name
     ORDER BY
        ORDINAL_POSITION
     FOR XML PATH('')) j (list)
where   xtype = 'U'
AND name    NOT IN ('dtproperties')
-- criteria
AND name like 'AUD_%'
order by OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(so.id),so.name

-- this execute one table only regardless how many table in actual result set 
exec (@sql)
```

Comment: why not use the built-in scripting functionality in SSMS?

Comment: If built-in scripting that you mean is right click the table, select script table as then select create to in SSMS, then it's mean I have to do that manually for every table that I need. I need to do bulk copy all tables that I need in one time.

Comment: Have you looked at what you are executing. It could be that you only build the create statement for one table. I see no string concatenation going on for each table.

Comment: Hi Mikael, it was the original question mean to be, which is how to generate and execute multiple create table statement above. However I have found solution for that requirement by using cursor.

Answer (score 2):

SSMS supports scripting all schema (and optionally data as INSERTS) in 2k8:

Right click on a database and select Tasks->Generate Scripts...

Select All tables OR Pick the tables you require, Click Next.

....

See answer here: to ["Script all data from SQL Server database"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6799120/script-all-data-from-sql-server-database)

That's a lot easier than trying to roll your own.

Comment: Hi Mitch, I still prefer to do it programmatically. I have hundreds tables and need only some table that match criteria. Using this feature will need me check or uncheck tables manually. For now all I need is how above script can be executed for individual 'create statement' that is generated.

Comment: so script out every table, and apply matching criteria to this text file? If you want to do it programmatically, I would suggest doing it with C# and SMO

Comment: select statement above will generate 'create table' statement for all tables that match criteria. Above, I pass that 'create table' statement to @sql variable. What I need is to execute every 'create table' statement generated using exec t-sql stored procedure. However I know in sql we might not just iterate result set and execute it like in programming language. For now I need only plain scripting way instead of using SSMS.