# Azure SQL Server to .sql dump file

Tags: sql-server, azure

I have an Azure SQL Server which I would like to dump out into a `.sql` file. How can I achieve this most easily, and preferably only using the provided tools? I have tried using the export functionality on the azure portal but that only seems to be for backing up the DB to another part of Azure. I need it to be a `.sql` dump file such that I can reconstruct this DB in postgres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something different than generating scripts with data?

This post discusses it:
[Script all data from SQL Server database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6799120/script-all-data-from-sql-server-database)